# Automount ecryptfs home in chroot (when using schroot)

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, chroot, ecryptfs, schroot

my host system is archlinux and i need an ubuntu enviornment ready to be used with the files in my home directory. Problem is: my home directory is encrypted using ecryptfs. So when i launch the schroot this is what i get:

```
 ~ $ schroot -c ubuntu-lts
(ubuntu-lts) ~ $ ls
Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop  README.txt
```

How can i automount my encrypted home directory (possibly without re-entering my password).

To setup my encrypted home on archlinux i have followed this:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ECryptfs#Encrypting_a_home_directory
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ECryptfs#Auto-mounting

My schroot setup is very simple:

```
~ $ cat /etc/schroot/chroot.d/ubuntu-lts.conf
[ubuntu-lts] 
type=directory 
description=Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
directory=/opt/schroot/ubuntu-lts 
users=<my username>
aliases=ubuntu-18.04,ubuntu-bionic,bionic
```

Comment: Can you log in (decrypting your home), and then run the schroot command? Doesn't it keep your home decrypted & usable?

Comment: Yes but it is mounted on host /home. What i would like to do is to have it mount on <chroot mount point>/home when i launch schroot command

Comment: chroot can't move the mount itself? Or maybe just `mount --bind` before chroot

Comment: Can you be more specific? Should i put in in /etc/schroot/default/fstab /home/<username> with bind option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution after a while:

schroot setup:

```
[ubuntu-lts]
type=directory
description=Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
directory=/opt/schroot/ubuntu-lts
users=<your-username>
aliases=ubuntu-18.04,ubuntu-bionic,bionic
setup.fstab=ubuntu-lts/fstab
```

And the fstab file becomes:

```
# fstab: static file system information for chroots.
# Note that the mount point will be prefixed by the chroot path
# (CHROOT_PATH)
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/proc           /proc           none    rw,bind         0       0
/sys            /sys            none    rw,bind         0       0
/dev            /dev            none    rw,bind         0       0
/dev/pts        /dev/pts        none    rw,bind         0       0
/home           /home           none    rw,bind         0       0
/tmp            /tmp            none    rw,bind         0       0
/home/<your-username>   /home/<your-username>   none    rw,bind         0       0

# It may be desirable to have access to /run, especially if you wish
# to run additional services in the chroot.  However, note that this
# may potentially cause undesirable behaviour on upgrades, such as
# killing services on the host.
#/run           /run            none    rw,bind         0       0
#/run/lock      /run/lock       none    rw,bind         0       0
#/dev/shm       /dev/shm        none    rw,bind         0       0
```

Which is simply the fstab file copied from /etc/schroot/default/fstab in /etc/schroot/ubuntu-lts/fstab where i added this line:

```
/home/<your-username>   /home/<your-username>   none    rw,bind         0       0
```